# Python swapping variables equivalent to C++11 swap? [a,b = b,a]

Tags: python, swap

A really neat way to swap variables is:

```
a,b = b,a
```

I was curios, so i've debugged it with the dis module and saw the **"ROT_TWO"** Instruction. Does ROT_TWO indicate that no data is copied but only pointers swapped? Basically the same as **std::move**? According to the "dis" documentation:

> ROT_TWO: Swaps the two top-most stack items.

At what context are a,b on the same stack?

**Code:**

```
import dis
def swap():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    a, b = b, a

dis.dis(swap)
```

**Output:**

```
3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  5          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 ROT_TWO             
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: If you're thinking in terms of `std::move`, or you think the details of the `ROT_TWO` bytecode would be important to whether a data copy occurs, you've misunderstood how Python variables work. They're nothing like C++ variables; in C++ terms, they're kind of like re-bindable references. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: They are **local variables**, and usually local variables are **pushed on the callstack**. Although afaik, every interpreter is free to handle memory in a free way.

Comment: Also see http://rg3.name/200704212054.html, which is specifically written for people coming from a C++ perspective.

Comment: Those are usefull tips! And thanks Willem for pointing out that local variables are being pushed on to the same callstack

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Sort of, but the stack involved in the `ROT_TWO` opcode and most other CPython bytecode instructions is actually a completely different stack from the call stack. The CPython interpreter is a [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine), like the JVM and unlike most physical processors these days, which are register machines.